# XAML Listbox Styled as radio button group with Title

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this style:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonList" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <!-- ControlTemplate taken from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242.aspx -->
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="80"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <Border 
                    Name="Border" 
                    Background="Transparent"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    CornerRadius="2">
                    <ScrollViewer 
                        Margin="0"
                        Focusable="false">
                        <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Border Name="theBorder" Background="Transparent">
                                <RadioButton Focusable="False"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </RadioButton>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Used as this :

```
        <ListBox                     
            Grid.Column="2"
            Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ModosConsultaSaldos}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Description"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ModoConsultaSaldos,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Shows something like this:

[image]

But now I want to add a Title using the same Style,

[image]

Is this posible?  How ?

Comment: `<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"><Label BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">Saldos</Label><ListBox .../></StackPanel>`. If for some reason you want the label text to be a property of the ListBox and displayed in the ListBox's Template, write an attached property. Or you could subclass the ListBox to add the property, but IMO that's overkill.

Comment: Tks. The label text could be any XAML resource. as x:static

Comment: `Label.Content` is `object`; it could be virtually anything at all. A viewmodel, a control, text, you name it.

Comment: Tks for your help. I'm not an expert on XAML and really don't know how to achieve that. Or At least How to use into a style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in a number of ways. The easiest is simply to stick a label in front of the ListBox in the XAML whenever you use it. But if you want to enforce a consistent style, you'll want something better than that.

We could add properties to ListBox by writing a subclass of ListBox that adds a `Header` property (I'm going to call it `Header` instead of `Title` because that's what a built-in WPF control would call it).

But a slightly more flexible option is to write the `Header` property as an attached property. We'll also throw in a `HeaderTemplate` attached property as well, so you can style the header content appropriately. This is common WPF practice in controls that have headers, such as `MenuItem` or `GroupBox`. Those WPF controls have `HeaderTemplateSelector` and `HeaderStringFormat` properties as well; I'll leave those as an exercise for the student.

First, the attached properties: This is all boilerplate except for the names and types.

```
public static class ListBoxEx
{
    public static Object GetHeader(ListBox obj)
    {
        return (Object)obj.GetValue(HeaderProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeader(ListBox obj, Object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Header", typeof(Object), typeof(ListBoxEx),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null) { AffectsMeasure = true, AffectsParentMeasure = true });


    public static Object GetHeaderTemplate(ListBox obj)
    {
        return (Object)obj.GetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeaderTemplate(ListBox obj, Object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderTemplate", typeof(Object), typeof(ListBoxEx),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null) { AffectsMeasure = true, AffectsParentMeasure = true });
}
```

Now we'll add these to the Template:

```
...
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
        <Border 
            Name="Border" 
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            CornerRadius="2"
            >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ContentControl
                    Content="{TemplateBinding local:ListBoxEx.Header}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding local:ListBoxEx.HeaderTemplate}"
                    />
                <ScrollViewer 
                    Margin="0"
                    Focusable="false"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    >
                    <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

And we'll give your Style another setter, to create a default header template that does the underlining you had in your screenshot:

```
        <Setter Property="local:ListBoxEx.HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label 
                        Content="{Binding}"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

And we use it like this:

```
    <ListBox
        Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ModosConsultaSaldos}"
        local:ListBoxEx.Header="Saldos"
        ...
        />
```

Comment: Amazing simple. First time I'm going to use  attached properties. Tks a lot for your help

Comment: Glad I could help.